# How to use emberjs action helper within custom registered helper?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, discourse

I may add actions within handlebars templates for emberjs with

```
<li>{{action "SomeAction" this}} {{this.name}}</li>
```

the SomeAction is called.

How may I add an action within an custom helper (this is only an example, I have more code in there):

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('foo', function(property, options) {
  var bar = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, property, options);

  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  args.unshift("someAction");
  args.unshift(bar);
  var action = Ember.Handlebars.helpers.action.apply(this, args);

  return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString("<li "+new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(action)+">"+bar.get("name")+"</li>");
});
```

This creates the same li tag, but it is not working, with this error when i click on the li tag (error message is from discourse app):

Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action ''. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.

Comment: the error indicates that no controller or route of the current context handles the specified action i.e. does not contain an `actions` property with a function specified in `foo` helper. Check out this example, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zudiqewo/1/edit  if in `hbs` template you rename `{{foo "test"}}` to `{{foo "teest"}}` you will receive the error you mentioned.

Comment: Thx, var bar = this; and your action works :) Make an answer and i will accept it :)

Comment: great i'm glad you worked it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that no controller or route of the current context handles the specified action i.e. does not contain an `actions` property with a function specified in `foo` helper.

Example, 
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zudiqewo/1/edit

**js**

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('foo', function(property, options) {

  var action = Ember.Handlebars.helpers.action.apply(this, arguments);

  return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString("<li "+new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(action)+">click here</li>");
});
```

if in `hbs` template the `test` is renamed from `{{foo "test"}}` to `{{foo "teest"}}` the aforementioned error will be thrown.